# Ordered Scatterplot with facets in ggplot with index

Tags: r, sorting, indexing, ggplot2

When i do something like

```
plot(diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),"depth"])
```

i get a plot of the sorted depth vector with indices as x-label.

Similar results with

```
ggplot(diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),], aes(x=seq(depth), y=depth)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Now i want to facet the graph by lets say color

```
ggplot(diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),], aes(x=seq(depth), y=depth)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(color~.)
```

[image]

But this does not what i want, i actually want to keep the plot ordered over all facets (same index as in the total graph). Btw I still want to keep the index as label for the x-Axis. 
Whats the proper way to do it?

Comment: not completely sure what you want. Is `df <- diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),]; df$seq <- seq(df$depth)` and then `ggplot(df, aes(x=seq, y=depth)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(color~.)` what you want?

Comment: Not very clear what you want. If you want a single shared y-axis then you can use facet_wrap(~colour, nrow=1). Can you give an example of a similar graph that you desire to replicate? Also, example data would help.

Comment: @rawr actually this seems to be the right answer, ty. 
I basically want the graphs to share the x-Axis with the x-Axis beeing the index the element would have in the sorted, complete dataframe (like in the first one). Basically i just want to partition the first graph. In the second image the points are not at the same x-Coordinate like before, but rawrs solution seems to accomplish exactly this. (btw its the diamonds example dataset library(ggplot2); data(diamonds))

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

One method I found was to create a new column that contains the indexing for each facet:

```
counts <- table(diamonds$color)
xindex <- integer(sum(counts)) # preallocate to required length with zero values
ci <- 1 # cumulative count for vector indexing
for (i in counts) {
    xindex[ci:(ci+i-1)] <- seq(i)
    ci <- ci+i
}
diamonds$xindex <- xindex
ggplot(diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),], aes(x=xindex, y=depth))
+ geom_point() 
+ facet_grid(color~.)
```

If each color happens to have exactly the same count, then the following code can be used:

```
xindex <- sapply(table(diamonds$color), seq) # matrix columns corresponds color
diamonds$xindex <- c(xindex[,1:ncol(xindex)]) # convert from matrix to integer vector 
ggplot(diamonds[order(diamonds$depth),], aes(x=xindex, y=depth))
+ geom_point() 
+ facet_grid(color~.)
```